# Use mysqli with XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I am using windows 10 and XAMPP control panel and coding in Visual Studio Code. PHP version is 8-6-2. XAMPP is not installed in /C, because of UAC and I couldn't deactivate it. When I write this  `$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');` 
Localhost prints error: Call to undefined function.

I flicked through all pages with the same titles and here is what I did: updated php.ini file(in xampp/apache uncommented 2 extensions), changed the port of Apache and mySQL in XAMPP control panel but the result is the same. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you restart the apache server?

Comment: @Dharman I tried to fins it in services, but it is not here. Can you tell me which one should I restart?

Comment: Well, if you don't know which button to press, it's easiest to just restart your PC. But XAMPP by the definition is the control panel where you can start and stop services.